# How to orderby woocommerce product categories as in the order I want?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

This is the query arguments. I want my products to appear according to categories arranged in the order I want.

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
                array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                      'field' => 'term_id',
                      'terms' => 12,
                      'operator' => 'NOT IN',           
                     )
     )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

Means, I want to specify the category order in the query somewhere..

```
array(3,4,5,7)
```

And products from category 3 will appear first, then 4, then 5 and so on.
How can I achieve this? Tried this plugin, but it seems it's not working with a custom query. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

Comment: Do not use `$wp_query` as your query variable. `$wp_query` is the global variable used to hold the main query object. What you are doing is breaking the main query object. To solve your issue, you will need to use `usort` on the returned array of posts

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks for that extra bit of information! So there is no in-built option for this in Wordpress? Strange. Thanks.

Comment: No unfortunately not. My pleasure, hope you get this sorted soon. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Just go under Appearance->Widgets
2. List item Under sidebar you added Woocommerce Product Categories expand "Woocommerce Product Categories"
3. List item At Order By dropdown box choose "Category Order" instead of Name.